# How to parse MIB and retrieve TEXTUAL-CONVENTION without OID in Python

Tags: python, parsing, snmp, pysnmp, mib

How to parse a MIB file in python and retrieve an object representing its TEXTUAL-CONVENTION?

For instance, CISCO-RTTMON-TC-MIB:

http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Html/C/CISCO-RTTMON-TC-MIB.php#RttMplsVpnMonRttType

Defines values: INTEGER jitter(1), echo(2), pathEcho(3)

Note that these objects *do not* have an OID number...

Desired result:

```
{"1": "jitter", "2": "echo", "3": "pathEcho"}
```

Comment: You might review its parser source code to see where text conventions are processed, https://github.com/etingof/pysmi

Answer (score 2):

Try using [pysmi](http://snmplabs.com/pysmi/mibdump.html) with its JSON code generation backend. That will give you the whole MIB in JSON form. That you can turn into a Python dict, walk it to get the items you need.

You can either use `mibdump` CLI tool or do the same in Python by calling pysmi library functions.